# Sticky footer for html5

Tags: css, html, footer, sticky

I want my footer to stick to the bottom of the page, so when the page is smaller than the screen, the footer should be on the bottom anyways. But it should not conflict with margin in the css file. So it should not mess up the page when I use margin for some stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create `wrapper div` and get out footer from there. Then make margin-bottom in this wrapper equal footer height and create some `push` div - it will be place for footer.
Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/PXYSk/4/

Comment: Maybe he left for the afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

Try using fixed position and the css3 `calc()` function:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PXYSk/)

Comment: This is the simplest and smallest solution so far!

Answer (score 0):

Just set the footer to `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example how to create sticky footer, but you need fixed height for footer block:

CSS:

```
* {
margin: 0;
}
html, body {
height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -50px;
}
.footer, .push {
height: 50px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css" ... />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p>Your website content here.</p>
        <div class="push"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
    </div>
</body>
```